# Event nofication on QUEUE_ACTIVATION stops working after queue is disabled and enabled again

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, service-broker

I am using Service Broker external activation. I have created event notification for queue (QUEUE_ACTIVATION). Currently making a lots of tests and sometimes my queue gets deactivated.

After enabling queue Event notification does not work anymore and external activator does not start console app.

i found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/172b96ee-006c-4b66-8952-8d655ad748d1), but that seems to be something else as "select * from sys.event_notifications" shows that there is already created event notification.

I do drop and create again the same event notification to make it work, but it seems to be wrong..

How can i detect automatically that event notification is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't RECEIVE and commit the notification from the monitoring queue, causing the notification to go into NOTIFIED state but never transitioning to RECEIVES_OCCURING. See [Understanding Queue Monitors](http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/).

Comment: I am using External activator "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Broker External Activator" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8824, so i am not consuming notification directly..